# React Native 'npm run ios' hanging after installing FontAwesome

Tags: react-native, font-awesome, react-font-awesome

I'm a React Native newbie and am working through a React Native Course on Udemy. I installed FontAwesome into my RN project (which is from the out-of-the-box setup of RN), and now when I run the `npm run ios` command it just hangs. I let it sit overnight, and it did make a little progress but was stuck on the 'building app' step. `npm run android` works fine.

I am on a Macbook with an M1 chip in case that complicates things.

Anyone know what the issue is and how to fix it?

Here is what I have tried unsuccessfully to fix the issue:

- Restarting my computer.
- Deleting the 'build' folder in my project's 'ios' folder.
- Recreating the project. It worked fine until I installed FontAwesome again.
- Running `killall -9 node`
- Deleting and rebuilding my node_modules folder.
- Rerunning `pod install` inside the 'ios' folder.
- Running `npx react-native run-ios` instead of `npm run ios` (which is set to `react-native run-ios`)